# (ESP8266) Check if a SSID is in range

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I need to check if a given SSID is in range. Would be good if it didn't disconnect from the current wifi network that it's connected to, but it doesnt matter, i just need to see if a SSID is in range, whether it does disconnect or not.
It should be something like this:

```
if(WiFi.SSID(checkforthisSSID)) {
  //do something
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not so tough it is possible just try the bellow code :)

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println("scan start");

  // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
  CheckPossibility();
  }

 CheckPossibility(){
 int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n == 0)
    Serial.println("no networks found");
  else
  {
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.println(" networks found");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      if(WiFi.SSID(i) == "REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR SSID"){ //enter the ssid which you want to search
      Serial.println("The network you are looking for is available");
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait a bit before scanning again
 // delay(5000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to connect to an AP, Use scan networks example, then look if the SSID in in the response.
Did not try, the scan networks example has an "WiFi.disconnect()" before the scan() function.